# How do I create DartDoc Macros/Templates in Dart and Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, dartdoc

I have seen snippets like the following throughout the Flutter repo:

```dart
/// {@macro flutter.widgets.editableText.readOnly}
```

In the IDE and in the rendered Dart docs, it is then [shown like this](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/TextField/readOnly.html):

> Whether the text can be changed.
>
> When this is set to true, the text cannot be modified by any shortcut or keyboard operation. The text is still selectable.
>
> Defaults to false. Must not be null.

And it tends to go way beyond this basic case.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can *create **templates*** and use them as **macros** using [`dartdoc`](https://pub.dev/packages/dartdoc), which is the default API documentation package that comes with Flutter.

Simply define an `@template` anywhere in your docs:

```dart
/// {@template template_name}
/// Some shared docs
/// {@endtemplate}
```

Now, you can reuse it anywhere else:

```dart
/// Some comment
/// {@macro template_name}
/// More comments
```

[Learn more](https://github.com/dart-lang/dartdoc#macros).